# fit_transform with the training data and transform with the testing

Tags: python, scikit-learn

As the title says, I am using `fit_transform` with the `CountVectorizer` on the training data .. and then I am using `tranform` only with the testing data ... will this gives me the same as using `fit` only on the training and `tranform` only on the testing data ?

Answer (score 5):

The answer is **YES** :

`fit_transform` is equivalent to `fit` followed by `transform`, but more efficiently implemented. [See documentation](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.feature_extraction.text.CountVectorizer.html#sklearn.feature_extraction.text.CountVectorizer.fit)

Both `fit`and `fit_transform` fit your classifier to your dataset. You can then use the same classifier to transform any other dataset (in your case the test set).

Comment: If I'm testing on the training data itself, then should I use `transform`  to generate the test features from raw training data? Or should I just use the result of `fit_transform` as both training and test features?

Comment: You need to transform your `test_train` using the `transform()` method

Answer (score 1):

If you use `fit` only on the training and `transform` on the test data, you won't get the correct result.

When using `fit_transform` on the training data, it means that the machine is learning from the parameters in the feature space and also transforming (scaling) the training data. On the other hand, you should only use `transform` on the test data to scale it according to the parameters learned from the training data.